# How to solve this complicated differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, computer-algebra-systems

I need to know how to solve this complicated differential equation in $z$ either analytically or numerically :

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dx_1}{dz} &=& -ib_1x_1 - ikx_2 \\
\frac{dx_2}{dz} &=& -i(b_2+c_2\cos(d_2z))x_2-ikx_1
\end{eqnarray}

where $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_2$, $d_2$, $k$ are constants, $i^2 = -1$ and initial condition $x_1(0)$, $x_2(0)$ are known also range of $z$.

Comment: For future reference: [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)